# Govee API responses with the error code 400

Tags: python, api, python-requests, http-status-code-400

I tried to change the color of my Govee lamp via the Govee API in Python but the status code returns 400. I looked up the Govee-API-Documentation, but this is all I could come up with:

```
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Govee-API-Key": self.govee_key2
}

body = {
    "device": self.pc_light_mac,
    "model": "H6003",
    "cmd": {
        "name": "color", 
        "value": {
            "r": 255, 
            "g": 255, 
            "b": 255
        }
    }
}

r = requests.put("https://developer-api.govee.com/v1/devices/control", headers=headers, params=body)
print(r.status_code)
```

I re-checked the mac address in the the Govee app, but still...
I tried to change another light, same issue
I tried other cmd's, still 400

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests    
url = f'https://developer-api.govee.com/v1/devices/control'    
headers = {
    'Govee-API-Key': api_key,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}    

content = {
    'device': device_id,
    'model': 'H6061',
    'cmd': {
        'name': 'turn',
        'value': 'on'
    }
}

response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, json=content)
```

Here's the code that I got working for this same task - you pass the juicy part under the 'json' keyword.